# Can you convert mesh to 2D curve in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have two mesh objects (simplified here to be a square and a Z-shaped mesh):

[image]

I would like to sweep Mesh #1 (the square) along the profile of Mesh #2 (the Z-shape), using Geometry Nodes. I do this by converting both to curve objects, and using the first one as a Profile Curve input, but it looks like this:

[image]

[Apparently the solution is to make the curve "2D" instead](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200083/150802), and this should remove the distortion. However I don't have access to this option (as far as I'm aware), because it is a mesh object in the object list. Is it possible to make the curve 2D in Geometry Nodes?

Note: A similar question exists [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/260113/150802), but I do not have the same requirement that the solution must work in 3D. I am only needing a solution in which the curve can be confined to a 2D plane.

Comment: Hello, I think this is a duplicate of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/260294/35559), if that works for you. If it doesn't, go ahead and edit this question, referring back and explaining the difference, and we can re-open it for you.

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts . I think it is not the same problem. In that case, the author specifically said he/she is trying to achieve a result in 3D. I do not have this requirement, and it would be sufficient for the curve to be restricted to a 2D plane in my case (which may admit a simpler solution).

Comment: OK, fair enough .. We'll see if @quellenform  agrees with you..

Comment: There's also [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/266230/35559), but for the reasons given, I think the other is better :)

Comment: This is the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - you want to do X: set your curve to 2D, in order to achieve Y: equal curve width. Indeed keeping the title and marking as the duplicate of quellenform's solution would be wrong. Except keeping the title is wrong, as it's asking for a technicality, rather than a result. I could be wrong though: someone in future might be looking to make a curve 2D for another reason: however considering how the X just isn't possible in geonodes... I vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I dont understand what you are saying. Are you saying dont use Geometry Nodes?

Comment: I'm saying use quellenform's answer.

Comment: Yes, it would work. But surely there is a simpler way in 2D.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but from my point of view there is currently no other viable solution than [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260113/) (and I have spent some time solving the problem and working on it intensively). It looks complex (and maybe it is), but it solves the task reliably and without creating unnecessary additional geometry. Of course you can still reduce the nodes (depending on your use case), but "simpler" is hardly possible atm, because this feature doesn't exist as a ready-made node. Robin's answer would be a good alternative, as I see it...

Comment: @quellenform Great, thanks for the comment, and for the work you put into this. Hopefully it will make it into a future update!